# Dropdown Box disappears on hovering over option contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a table with a Dropdown box in each row which shows on click, using AngularJs. The problem I am facing is, whenever I click on the Dropdown box and try to hover on the option contents to select one of them, the dropdown box disappears. Unable to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. I am using Mozilla Firefox browser and Ubuntu 13.10

P.S- I have tested this on Windows Chrome and it seems to work fine but the requirement is to make it work on Mozilla Firefox as well.

[This is my code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JD9FPKTAicaj0rvkDOvd?p=preview)

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, it works fine in chrome

Answer (score 1):

This is because code

```
ng-mouseleave="showSelect=false"
```

Remove it at all or play around it

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-mouseleave="showSelect=false"
```

Causes in FF to close/hide the select when your mouse is outside the td.
This also happens when your mouse is hovering over the options outside the td.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you juste remove the onmouseleave event on your TD ?

It's working without :

http://plnkr.co/edit/TS4QOwNyxtzpDRoREMcA?p=preview

Comment: The requirement is to hide the dropdown on mouseleave and show the label.