# selectedIndex event fires when mouse hovering options or moving the cursor top to bottom in the dropdown in mozilla firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem with the dropdown in firefox. When I mouse hover the dropdown items or moving the cursor on the items the selectedindex event of dropdown fires in firefox and I am not facing this problem in IE,chrome.

```
    .aspx:
 Collapse | Copy Code
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTempGroups" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlTempGroups_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="-" Value="-" > 
<asp:ListItem Text="type" Value="type" >
<asp:ListItem Text="date" Value="date" >
</asp:DropdownList>


.cs
protected void ddlTempGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393494). As stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507389/dropdown-box-disappears-on-hovering-over-option-contents), you can try:

```
ng-mouseleave="showSelect=false"
```

Comment: Hi, Actually my question is ,the event is firing with just mouse hovering the dropdown items and i am not selecting any dropdown items.  The link u referred is saying about the disappearing the dropdown

Comment: what about the "known bug" link? is it irrelevant, too?